# Line not following x os correctly & first tick isn't being shown

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis

See: http://jsfiddle.net/bQHjj/

Following the green line, the circles should be vertically aligned with my x axis, but all of them are moved a few pixels to the right.

The X axis isn't showing it's first tick, which should be 01.05.2013.

My x axis settings:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).ticks(d3.time.days, 1).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d.%m.%Y"));

graph.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "rotate(-65)"
    });
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date parsing function is not correct, it seems to mess up time zones, since `new Date(string)` apparently assumes UTC.
This will work:

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
function getDate(d) {
    return format.parse(d.date);
}
```

cf the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQHjj/1/).